# How to access Tomcat libraries for Java application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2, netbeans-7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a relatively easy way to add jar files to Tomcat 7 folders in the Elastic Beanstalk cloud (specifically WEB-INF/lib)? I use Netbeans 7.3 and try to connect to a RDS database instance.

Comment: Do you want to use container(tomcat) managed connection pool? If not, you can just deploy mysql jar with war. Otherwise, you must use Configuration File or Custom AMI to customize your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to connect using the DriverManager+mysql jar which was deployed correctly with the project when I copied it into the WEB-INF/lib manually (had to create the lib folder as well). Thanks for pointing me in the config file or custom AMI direction as I've been struggling with setting up the DataSource. Now I know I have have to read up on AMI:s and config files, thanks!